# Why does rotating Pearson's $r$ in my simulation reduce its $MSE$? And could you use this with real data to improve $MSE$?

Tags: correlation, monte-carlo, pearson-r, mse, methodology

I've been running some Monte Carlo simulations in R to determine the impact on $MSE$ of rotating Pearson's $r$ (the sample statistic, not its data) by itself at various angles, for multiple levels of population correlation and $n$. To be clear, I'm generating the samples using mvrnorm with empirical = FALSE, rotating using the code `matrix(cbind(r.est,r.est),length(r.est),2)%*%matrix(c(cos(Angle),sin(Angle),-sin(Angle),cos(Angle)),2,2)` and computing $MSE$ with `var(r.est)+(mean(r.est)-rho)^2)`.

Summarizing my observations:

For any magnitude of $rho$ greater than zero and sample size $n$, there exists an angle greater than zero to which the observed Pearson's $r$ may be rotated, such that its empirical $MSE$ is reduced to some minimal point. There is also a larger angle to which $r$ may be further rotated, at which $r$ returns to its unrotated $MSE$. The initial drop in $MSE$ occurs because standard error decreases with larger angles at a rate faster than bias toward zero increases; the later increase in $MSE$ occurs because bias eventually gets so large as to cancel out the benefit of shrinking the standard error. The larger the population correlation, the smaller the two angles.

Now, if this is accurate, it implies the following procedure for real data: choose some outlandishly large effect size magnitude (say, .6 for a typical educational intervention) called $rhoMax$, use Monte Carlo simulations to determine the appropriate (larger) angle of rotation for $rhoMax$ to return to its original $MSE$, and then rotate my real-world study's observed $r$ by itself to that angle. So long as the population correlation actually is between $-.6$ and $+.6$, I'm guaranteed a better estimate, with the maximum benefit at zero population correlation.

A quick example: $n = 15$, $rhoMax = .6$, angle of rotation $= .125$ radians. When $rho = 0$, and before rotating $r$, $MSE = .0711$. After rotation, $MSE = .0535$. The $MSE$ at $rho = 0$ is reduced by nearly $25$ percent (!). The improvement in $MSE$ gradually diminishes as the population correlation rises from $0$ to $.6$ but only exceeds the unrotated $MSE$ above $.6$.

Can someone explain this? Could it be an artifact of the simulation? If it were to work in real life, that seems like getting a free lunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To possibly make this less mysterious, consider a Normal mean and consider just scaling it.
With data from $N(\mu,1)$, $\bar X_n\sim N(0,1/n)$ has MSE $1/n$

$\alpha\bar X_n\sim N(\alpha\mu, \alpha^2)$ has MSE
$$(1-\alpha)^2\mu^2+\alpha^2n= (\mu^2-2\alpha\mu^2+(\mu^2+1/n)\alpha^2) $$
[image]
As $\alpha$ decreases from 1, the MSE decreases at first, because the increase in bias is outweighed by the decrease in variance, then the trend reverses.  If you know, say, $\mu\in [-0.6,0.6]$, you can pick a value of $\alpha$ that reduces the bias for all $\mu$ in that range, with the biggest reduction being at $\mu=0$.

The small reduction in MSE is real, but it goes away pretty fast as $n$ increases, and requires knowing a bound on $\mu$. It also requires that MSE is what you care about -- that you're happy to trade variance for bias, and give up on confidence interval coverage.

In three or more dimensions you can get reduced MSE in a somewhat related way for *all* values of $\mu$ (though it still goes away as $n$ increases) using the James-Stein estimator.

Comment: I've heard of James-Stein, in the context of estimating 3+ estimators simultaneously to minimize their collective MSE, so that analogy is very helpful. J-S seemingly rarely shows up in practice since we usually have measures of individual parameters, which we care about individually. It never occurred to me something similar might happen for a single parameter! Looking across larger samples, I see how it rapidly diminishes. Still, now that I know, I can account for the effect. Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know of a general term or label that would flag this concept in, say, textbooks or articles? My other issue, in addition to figuring out what the heck was happening, was that I immediately hit a wall in my search. J-S just brings up MV cases, but maybe shrinkage?

Comment: I think shrinkage is the best term, though most uses of it will be for the high-dimensional setting.  It's also related to Bayesian estimation: you're using prior assumptions about the plausible values of $\rho$ to improve your estimate (if the assumptions are correct), and you could get basically similar results with a formal prior distribution.